# How to prove that the range of this function is $ [−1,1]$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry, graphing-functions

We have the equation $\quad x^2 \Big(\sqrt{1-y^2} \sin (x)-\sin (4 x)\Big)+2 x y=0\quad$  for  $\,\,\,x>0\,\,$ and $y$ is real. I want to solve this equation for $y$. Solving the quadratic equation, I obtain:
$$y=\frac{\pm \sqrt{2} \sqrt{x^4 \sin ^2(x) (-\cos (2 x))+x^4 \sin ^2(x) \cos (8 x)+8 x^2 \sin ^2(x)}+4 x \sin (4 x)}{2 \left(x^2 \sin ^2(x)+4\right)}$$
Now, when I plot this function, I get

[image]

Can please someone explain why it always lays in $[-1,1]$? And, if it is true, then, is there a way to prove that the range of this function is $[-1,1]$?

Comment: Well, initially you have $\sqrt{1-y^2}=F(x,y)$, so $y\in[-1,1]$.

Comment: Note that the domain and codomain are parts of the data of a function.

Comment: @Mariya If $|y|>1$, then the initial expression is not defined.

Comment: Read up the definition of a function. A function is some assignment (in some set-theoretic sense) $f:A \to B$, so you should mention what $A,B$ are to define a function.

Answer (score 1):

If $|y| > 1$, how are you planning to get $x\left(\sqrt{1-y^2} \sin(x) - \sin(4x) \right)+2y$ to come out purely real?

Comment: $y$ *is* the range. It assumes values in the range only. Label your axes and this becomes obvious!

Comment: May I ask you to delete your answer, if possible? I want to delete this question. Regards

Comment: Why delete the question? Per https://math.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question, there's a reason why the system is preventing you from doing so yourself!

Comment: I do not think that this question took much time from the contributors. And also, your answer is not an answer, but is a question! Others answered better but as a comment.